# Can a C++ map contain a pointer to my arbitrary class?

Tags: c++, pointers, stl, dictionary

I am writing a small game engine as a summer project, and am struggling a little with the STL map.

I have declared a class `RenderList` to hold objects. The RenderList will be passed to a `Renderer` class to do the work.

The `RenderList` has a `map<std::string,Entity*> objects;`

That all works, till I try to obtain an `Entity*` from the map and I get:

Assertion failed, in vc/include/xtree
Expression: map/set iterator not dereferencable.

This is the code to retrieve the pointer.

```
Entity* RenderList::getByName(std::string str){
    return objects.find(str)->second;
}
```

I need it to hold a pointer and not the actual object, as there are different sub-classes of `Entity` which I'll need.

I am fairly new to the STL, should I not store pointers in a map?

Surely I should be allowed to do this, or is it a better idea to store objects instead?

And finally, am I simply doing it wrong!?

Hope this question is not a duplicate, I did do a quick search beforehand. Also if this would be better in the GameDev Stack I'll post it there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the key is not found then `map::find(key)` returns a "past-the-end" iterator, i.e. the value returned by `map::end()`, and that iterator doesn't point to any element so can't be dereferenced. You do not check what `find` returns before dereferencing it.

Are you sure they key is in the map?

You probably want to do something like return NULL if the key isn't found, which you can check for by comparing the returned iterator to `end` e.g.

```
Entity* RenderList::getByName(std::string str){
  map_type::iterator it = objects.find(str);
  if (it == objects.end())
    return NULL;
  return it->second;
}
```

Where `RenderList` defines the typedef:

```
typedef map<std::string,Entity*> map_type;
```

(N.B. I *always* make my classes define typedefs for the containers I use as implementation details, because it's much easier to write `map_type::iterator` than `map<std::string,Entity*>::iterator` and because if I change the container to something else I don't have to change all the code using it to e.g. `map<std::string,shared_ptr<Entity>>::iterator` I can just leave it as `map_type::iterator` and it still works perfectly.)

Regarding the general design, can you store a `boost::shared_ptr<Entity>` or `std::tr1::shared_ptr<Entity>` instead of a raw pointer? It will be much safer and simpler to manage the object lifetimes.

Comment: Thanks very much. This was indeed the problem. I hadn't noticed as the entity was created much higher up. I've never used boost, and frankly it scares me a little, I don't want to delve into more libraries that I won't understand quite yet. I think I will at some point, then I'll be back with more questions!

Comment: @Finlaybob, I think that's a big mistake, very seriously. There's no reason to use (or even look at) all of Boost at once. Using `boost::shared_ptr` is as simple as including one header and will prevent a **lot** of errors that you're likely to make using raw pointers to dynamically allocated objects. The reason C++ has a bad reputation with some people for complicated memory handling is only because some people refuse to use the tools like `shared_ptr` that make it simple and safe. Even if you never touch the rest of Boost you should stop managing memory the hard way ASAP.

Answer (score 3):

That probably means that the name you were looking for does not exist in the map. If the key does not exist, `find` method return the end iterator for the map, which is indeed not dereferencable.

If the "not found" situation is something that can naturally happen, then you can do this

```
Entity* RenderList::getByName(std::string str){
    map<std::string,Entity*>::iterator it = objects.find(str);
    return it != objects.end() ? it->second : NULL;
}
```

thus passing on the responsibility to handle this situation to the caller.

If the "not found" situation is not supposed to happen, either throw an exception or at least do

```
assert(it != objects.end());
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing wrong with this is that you need to handle the case where the there is no entry which matches `str`. Not sure what the specific error is about however as I've (regrettably) done the same dip into a map to retrieve a pointer..

Answer (score 1):

If the map does not contain the key you pass to the `find` method, then it will return `objects.end()`. Dereferencing this is a runtime error and will likely cause the error you see. Try instead:

```
map<std::string,Entity*>::iterator findIt;
findIt = objects.find(str);

if ( findIt != objects.end() )
{
    return findIt->second;
}
else
{
   // Handle error here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, the name that you are looking up doesn't exist in the map. Everyone is quick to suggest that you check the return value of `.find()`. I suggest, instead, that you don't call `.find()`. Here is how I would solve your problem:

```
Entity* RenderList::getByName(std::string str){
  return objects[str];
}
```

In the code above, looking up a non-existent map entry will create an entry with a NULL pointer value, and return NULL.

You need to add some code *somewhere* to check for a null pointer before you deference it.

Comment: Well, the question is whether it is a good idea to create a new entry for non-existing values. Also, a method called `getByName` might likely get declared `const` eventually, which will make operator `[]` unavailable.

Comment: In general this is not what you want to do. If you look up lots of invalid keys for every valid one you'll fill the map with invalid entries and slow down lookup significantly.